# File upload to server upload directory by using ajax. The image is not getting uploading to upload directory; getting the error of connection reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, netbeans

File upload to server upload directory by using ajax the image is not 
getting uploading to the upload directory. I'm getting the error of "connection 
reset". Please let me know the mistake I am doing in the below code. I created 
the upload directory in the site root in the netbeans IDE.

```
<body>       

 <form method="post" action= "upload">           
     <input type=file id="media" name=media>
    <input type="submit">         
 </form>
 </body>
```

jquery code to upload the image to upload folder.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      
  $(form).on('submit',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();        
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

   $.ajax({

       type:'POST',         
       url:'upload',
       data :formData,        

       processData:false,        
       contentType:false,

       success:function()          
       {
            alert('File uploaded');        
       }       
     });            
    });       
});
```

Comment: how much is the size of file you are trying to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);` outside of `$(document).ready(function(){`
something like the below added lines
`var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#formID").on('submit', function(event) {`